# Call a ruby method with different parameters embedded in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this `ruby` method:

```
def something(sometext, jsvariable, rubyobject)
   return HTMLOBJECT
end
```

And I would like to call this method like this in a `javascript` function:

```
$("#someid").append('<% something("sometext", '/jsvar/', rubyobject) %>');
```

Its not working.I don't know how to call this method from a `javascript` function with proper 
formatting of the variables. I don't really know the exact syntax for it.

Any help is much appreciated.

**UPDATE: This is what I'm trying to do**

```
function somejsfunc(){
  $.ajax({ 
    url: "/app/SomeController/someMethod",
    data: {'something': something }
    success: function(data){
      var $response1 = $(data);
      jsvar = $response1.find('#anotherselector').text();
      $("#someid").append('<% something("sometext", '/jsvar/', @rubyobject) %>');
    }
 });
}
```

**Please Note**

```
def something
```

is a generic method which returns a HTML DOM element based on these parameters,along with
other data passed into it.Thanks.

Comment: You will need a route to your method in rails which leads to your `something` method. In the Ajax-call you have to specify that rout with the desired parameters. These will end up in your controller method in the regular `params` hash and you would have to continue from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally our `ruby` runs on the server and your `JavaScript` runs in the browser, so calling one from the other is pretty much impossible. You may of course resort to Ajax as @uselesssmile suggester, but that involves a whole lot more than a simple method call. On the other hand you can compile your `ruby` to `JavaScript` using [`opalrb`](http://opalrb.org), then you can package it into your `JavaScript` on the client and call it directly.

Comment: See the thing is,If I call like this: $("#someid").append('<% something("sometext") %>') ;, it is working fine,but it is not recognizing the js and the ruby variable being passed(I'm not sure how to pass it rather!)

Comment: And this method is not a controller method.It is defined in a common module.

Comment: @Rajarshi: You can call controller methods through appropriate settings in your `routes.rb`, there you can parse parameters, pass them to your `ruby` method and package the result to return it. You will have a tough time doing otherwise as long as your `ruby` runs on your server. As I suggested the other approach is using `opalrb` to compile your ruby into `JavaScript` which can be distributed along with your other scripts to the browser. Most plain `ruby` modules can simple be included into an `opal` file.

Comment: Ok got it.Thanks.Cannot upvote for my rep.Same goes for @uselesssmile.

Comment: @Rajarshi: You *should* be able to accept an answer though, it should do good to your rep. too.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this, because erb templates compiles before application startup. Use remote requests to take info from server if you want send some js parameters.

UPD: Something like this

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/some_url',
   data: { jsvar: jsvar },
   success: function(data) {
       $("#someid").append(data.sometext);
   }
});
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate how??

Comment: Actually this is inside an ajax call.The rubyobject is one from the call,and the jsvar has the text of a specified DOM element received from the 'data' of the call request.

Comment: Just use this ruby method `something` on the server.